# Remove two characters all occurrence in a string using a pattern

Tags: php

```
$str = "XXXX, P.a and XXXXXX, M.a and XXXXX, V.c and XXXXXX, M.w and XXXXX, I.b and XXXXá";
```

In the above string, I want to remove '.' and next alphabet character(a-z) in all occurrence. I tried the below preg_replace. But it removes all lower case characters :(

```
echo $str = preg_replace("/.[a-z]/u","", $str);
```

I need output

```
XXXX, P and XXXXXX, M and XXXXX, V and XXXXXX, M and XXXXX, I and XXXXá
```

How to solve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $str = preg_replace("/\\.[a-z]/u","", $str);
```

You need to escape the `.`, since that means "any character" in a regular expression.

Output:

> XXXX, P and XXXXXX, M and XXXXX, V and XXXXXX, M and XXXXX, I and XXXXá